# Show posts in UITableView Cell With Background fetch

Tags: ios, uitableview, background-image

I am creating a app in which I have to show user posts which includes photos and text. I want a better way to fetch newer posts in Background like those in Facebook? and after scroll to top I want to show the newer posts.

Comment: You need to explain `fetch those posts in Background like those in Facebook` in more detail... if all you want is lazy loading, asking for and tagging `background fetch` is not appropriate as it refers to a whole different concept in iOS viz. fetching content when app is not running in fore ground... most probably there are many questions with valid answers for what you are trying to do...

Comment: I want to fetch newer posts and show those posts on the tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` schedule the image and posts to be downloaded on separate thread for each cell, and as the images and posts are downloaded update the corresponding cells with the received data.

For downloading the images and posts You can use lazy loading, also you can asynchronously download your resources using GCD API as-

```
// sample usage of GCD API
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = nil; // or cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        // download the image asynchronously as
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://imageurl.com/%@.jpg",[[modal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imageId"]]]];
        if (imgData) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            if (image) {
                // when the image is downloaded set it as
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    UITableViewCell *updateCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    if (updateCell)
                        updateCell.imageView.image = image;
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return cell;
}
```

**Note**: This is a rough idea to do so, you need to use/ implement the same as per your needs.

Comment: When i am using this method my table view starts freezing. its not scrolling smoothly.. any Ideas?

Comment: can you show your source of how'd you used above code?

Comment: UIImage *imageFromCache = [self.imageCache objectForKey:post_image_url]; if (imageFromCache) {
            imagePost.image = imageFromCache;  } else  { imagePost.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
      [self.imageOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{NSURL *imageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:post_image_url];UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageurl]]; if (img != nil) {  [self.imageCache setObject:img forKey:post_image_url];  [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ if (cell) { [imagePost setImage:img];  }  }]; }  }]; }

Comment: @Cqlsys, can you please replace your image downloading code with the code I have provided above in my answer, doing so your table will be scrolling very smoothly

Comment: I have tried using it .. It show some error.

Comment: whats's the error message?